# Rails 4: Send email to an other reciever than in :to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, email, ruby-on-rails-4, actionmailer

I'm writing a mailinglist software in rails and I want to send a recieved email to all the subscribers.

Normally a recieved email from a mailinglist has the sender in the `:from` key and the address of the mailinglist in the `:to` key. So it is easy to see who has written the mail and that this mail is for/from the mailinglist.

I generate the mail (in extracts) this way:

```
mail[:reply_to] = mailinglist.email

mail.delivery_method.settings.merge!(smtp_settings)
mail.deliver
```

Now I want to deliver it to `subscriber.email`, but it is delivered back to the mailinglist (because I don't overwrite `mail[:to]`). But when I overwrite it with `mail[:to] = subscriber.email` the email contains not the mailinglist as reciever address.

Is it possible to send an email to a other address than in `:to`?

**Edit:**
It is also possible to put all subscribers in `:bcc` and the mailinglist address in `:to`, but in this case how can I avoid the sending to the `:to` reciever?

Comment: You can't avoiding, only way is to skip to field altogether but I'm not sure if spam filters will like it.

Comment: How can i do this? Then i can test if spam filters would detect these mails as spam.

Comment: I don't know any way to do that. There are many different filters. Also, don't you think such tool would be a dream for spammers?

Comment: I think you dont know, how a mailinglist work. You have to subscribe to post in a mailinglist. And the tool do not skipping the default email spam filters.

Answer (score 0):

The way this is usually achieved is to put recipients in `BCC` field of email (hidden copy) so email actually gets delivered but recipients don't see each other's addresses.

Comment: I added a Edit for this suggestion. But it solves not the problem, because with a `:bcc` the mailinglist doesn't occure as normal reciever of the mail. And with the mailinglist address in `:to` additionally, i send the mail also back to the list.